# Is a curve with one-sided tangents rectifiable?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $\gamma\colon I\to\mathbb R^3$ be a simple curve where $I=[a,b]$ is a closed interval. Let
$$L(\xi,\eta)=\frac{\gamma(\eta)-\gamma(\xi)}{\|\gamma(\eta)-\gamma(\xi)\|}.$$

Flett [1] defines $\gamma$ to have an $\alpha$-tangent at $t$ if $L(\xi,\eta)$ converges when $\xi\to t$ and $\eta\to t$ in such a way that $\xi<\eta$. He proves that if $\gamma$ has an $\alpha$-tangent at every point in $I$, then $\gamma$ is rectifiable.

He mentions that "we can also define the tangents at $t$ from the left
and from the right by imposing the obvious restrictions on $\xi$ and $\eta$," i.e., $\gamma$ has an $\alpha$-tangent at $t$ from the left if $L(\xi,\eta)$ has a limit when $\xi\nearrow t$ and $\eta\nearrow t$ in such a way that $\xi<\eta$, etc.

My question is: Is it also true that if $\gamma$ has an $\alpha$-tangent at every point in $I$ from the left and from the right (but the limits of $L(\xi,\eta)$ are not necessarily the same at a point $t$), then $\gamma$ is rectifiable?

Of course, if there are only finitely many points where the left and right tangents are different, $\gamma$ is rectifiable by Flett's result, but I don't know if it still holds if the tangents are different at, say, countably infinitely many points.

[1] Flett, T. M. "The Definition of a Tangent to a Curve." Edinburgh Mathematical Notes 41 (1957): 1-9.
https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/edinburgh-mathematical-notes/article/the-definition-of-a-tangent-to-a-curve/42524F8015A1B601BA4DDDDAF005AE34

Answer (score 1):

Let $s(t_0,t)$ be the length of $\gamma([t_0,t])$ in the usual sense (with the value $\infty$ being permitted, in which case $\gamma([t_0,t])$ is not rectifiable). Theorem 3 in Flett's paper is also true when tangents from the left and right exist at $t_0$, namely that
$$\frac{s(t_0,t)}{\|\gamma(t_0)-\gamma(t)\|}\to 1\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{s(t,t_0)}{\|\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_0)\|}\to 1$$
as $t\searrow t_0$ and $t\nearrow t_0$, respectively.

Hence, $\gamma$ is rectifiable in an interval around every point in $I$. Assume for contradiction that $\gamma$ is not rectifiable. Let
$$R=\{t\in I\mid \gamma([a,t])\text{ is rectifiable}\}.$$
If $R=[a,c]$ for some $c\in I$, then $R$ can be extended to the right since $\gamma$ is rectifiable in an interval around $c$. Consider the case where $R=[a,c)$ is open to the right. Since $\gamma$ is rectifiable in an interval around $c$, then $R$ can be extended also in this case, which is a contradiction.